# Как применить Voice Actions к своему приложению?

Tags: android

Хочу использовать в своем приложении кастомный `Voice Actions`, чтобы запускать не стандартные приложения, а своё. Как это реализовать? Чтобы я говорил: "Ok, Google" -> "Direct Match" и запускалось бы моё приложение.

Я нашел эту статью [What are Google Now Voice Actions?](http://blog.prolificinteractive.com/2015/11/06/implementing-google-voice-actions-into-your-android-app/) но не знаю, что прописывать в моем `Manifest`.

Можно пошагово, что мне для этого нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь вы не можете указать своё приложение для реакции на произвольный шаблон команд. Вы можете только добавить в свои интент фильтры действия [этой таблици](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Now)
При этом пользователь может запустить ваше приложение сказав  "Ok, Google" -> "Запусти Direct Match" даже если у вас ничего и не настроено. А вот если хотите реагировать на запрос "Ok, Google" -> "search for cat videos 
on Direct Match" (не знаю аналогичный формат для русского языка), то видимо надо добавить в фильтры

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE"/>
</intent-filter>
```